# Prove that the multiplication of intervals is itself an interval

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know how should I show or prove that some A = [a, b] is an interval on real numbers.

for example how can I prove that the result of interval multiplication or addition is itself an interval.
$$A+B=C=>[a, b] + [c, d] = [a+c, b+d]$$
I know intuitively and by using examples that the result of these operations is an interval but how can I prove it? what should I show to prove it?

thanks

Comment: What do you means for ''interval multiplication or addition''  ?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are intervals, would you mean multiplication in this (pretty standard) sense:
$$
AB = \{ab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}?
$$

Comment: @EmilioNovati I add the addition example.

Comment: @Arthur: Yeah, I mean the multiplication that is in interval arithmetic:
$$[a, b] * [c, d]=[min(ac,ad,bc,bd), max(ac,ad,bc,bd)]$$

Answer (score 1):

How fancy do you want to go? If your intervals are $I$ and $J$, then $I\times J$ is a rectangle (open, closed or half-and-half), which in any event is a connected topological space. The product map from $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous, and the image of a connected space is connected. And the only connected subspaces of $\Bbb R$ are the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

For now consider the simpler case where $a, a'>0$.  You want to prove that $$[a,b]\cdot [a',b']=[aa',bb']$$
Each side is a set, so to prove that you need to prove two set containments:
$$[a,b]\cdot [a',b']\subseteq [aa',bb']$$
and
$$[a,b]\cdot [a',b']\supseteq[aa',bb']$$

There are cases that arise when an interval contains negative numbers.

Fortunately, for the addition version, there are no cases, just the two containments.

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't want to show that these things are equal. I just want to show that what I get in the interval multiplication is itself an interval. Are these two the same? showing the equality and the case that the result is an interval?

Comment: I have no idea how to show that the result is an interval without knowing which interval it is, without using topology (as in Lubin's solution).